# Windows DPAPI - what to do with entropy?

Tags: .net, security

I'm using the Windows DPAPI to encrypt some sensitive data for me. The cipher is stored in the registry. This all works well, but I was wondering if someone could clarify my understanding of the 'entropy' bytes that are (optionally) supplied to ProtectedData.Protect() in .NET.

The 'entropy' byte array appears to be analogous to an initialization vector or salt used with other cryptography schemes, but I could not see a good description of the entropy bytes in MSDN. The code samples I've seen just hard code in the entropy bytes!

Are the entropy bytes supplied to ProtectedData.Protect() & ProtectedData.Unprotect analogous to an IV or salt? Can the entropy bytes therefore be stored safely alongside the cipher, or would that compromise security?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Entropy is a secondary key that is specific to the application that is protecting data. The general idea, if I remember correctly, was to allow multiple applications to encrypt data under a single user account, but still maintain security between each other. For example, Your application may encrypt data under UserA. If My application wished to decrypt that data under UserA, there really isn't anything to stop my from doing so, as the DPAPI uses the users key. However, if you factor in an application specific "entropy", then I would need to know your entropy to decrypt any data to protect for UserA.

Entropy could be considered analogous to salt, in that it is an additional key or secret used to further abstract the encrypted content. Unlike salt, your application's entropy would need to remain the same for every encryption operation under a given credential. With salt, its generally best to change it as often as you can.

Entropy is essentially an additional key, and it should be treated like any other cryptographic key. Keep it private and secure.

BTW, I think 'entropy' was an atrocious word to use for this purpose. Something like 'differentiator', or perhaps even coining a word like 'distinctifier', would have been better. :P Very confusing term use.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. So I guess hardcoding the entropy into the app is not a complete disaster, but better to treat it like a key. Since I'm encrypting a key anyway, having another "key" to protect the key is becoming a bit crazy.

Comment: Aye, its a bit of a convoluted concept. But the security hole that "entropy" aims to plug is very real. Credential-specific encryption in windows is very convenient for the user, but it opens new opportunities for malicious programs to decrypt that data when they shouldn't. Also, don't assume that any "other" program is benign...malware that the user doesn't even know is on their system may try to probe for encrypted data that isn't entropic.

Answer (score 3):

One use of additional entropy is to password protect the application itself. A key derived from the password can be used as entropy while storing application data. Otherwise any process running under the user's context may be able to decrypt the data. If you store the additional entropy instead of prompting for a password, it could still be targeted by a rogue application.