# Secure (hide) Connection String Credentials (detais) in Access Vba

Tags: vba, string, security, ms-access, connection

We have several applications in Access/VBA (2013, 64 bits) and the data is stored locally and we want to start saving the data in SQL Server over the network, but connection  credentials are **visible inside Access and over the network when using ADO**.

We only have one password to access the sqlserver (ex. user: s1234, pass: 12345)

I found this post -> [How to securely store Connection String details in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217014/how-to-securely-store-connection-string-details-in-vba) here in stack overflow, but I easily decompiled the dll generated as described in that thread using **.NET Reflector 9.0** and I was able to see the credentials in clear text (it doesn't fit as a secure solution to our problem).

Is there a solution to this using Access or how can I hide (encrypt) these credentials using only access or using a DLL. Is there a solution to this?

Other resources I looked:

- http://www.dotnetspark.com/links/2849-protect-it-safeguard-database-connection.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/243.security-developer-resources.aspx
- [How to Hide connection string in windows forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460903/how-to-hide-connection-string-in-windows-forms-application)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use SQL Server authentication?  Why not Windows authentication?

Comment: The company where I work is very unflexible with the sqlserver configuration. I think windows authentication would be best, but at this moment that is not an option. they only allow us to have one account that is dbowner. We, in a certain way, have to use access because there are a lot of automated tasks in Internet Explorer and Attachmate Extra. I read that in C# there's a way to encrypt the connection string, but I have no idea at all about that. I'm starting to learn c# this year so that we can migrate these applications.

Answer (score 0):

I publish my Access applications as `.accde`, which conceals the source code. Other than that, I'm not so sure there is a surefire way to encrypt your connection strings.  If security is a major concern with you Access database, it might be worth looking into setting Windows authentication on your SQL server or migrating your application to a web-based application in something like C#.net

Comment: With a quick google search I found that accde can be decompiled with services like: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/unlocking-access-accde-fi-t1947839.html It could be a short term solution but I find it insecure. There are also other online services that provide this "decompile" service. Accde to accdb